# Jmeter If controller condition statement

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to built a test plan in jmeter where i want to run test for specific **HTTP request** based on their names. I used if controller but I dont know what condition to write.

I am writing `${__samplerName()}=="HTTPRequestName"` in the condition but it isn't executing.
kindly help me as soon as possible.

Comment: Can you show us the full, failing block of code?

Comment: Its not even starting the execution. can you please tell me how to write the condition in If controller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to surround `${__samplerName()}` with quotation marks as follows:

```
"${__samplerName()}"=="HTTPRequestName"
```

See [How to use JMeter's 'IF' Controller and get Pie.](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) guide for more details on If Controller use cases and clauses.

In case if you need to run samplers basing on some condition, you can use JMeter Properties as follows:

1. Launch JMeter providing sampler name property like `jmeter -Jrunsomesampler=true`
2. Add If Controller with the following condition: `${__P(runsomesampler,)} == true`
3. Add desired HTTP Requests as a children of the IF Controller

[image: If Controller]

Comment: Still not working. See i have built a test plan to test HTTP REQUEST and check the post response. I have included multiple samplers but out those samplers i want to run only those samplers with a specific name. is there any method i can do this?

Comment: Got it. `__samplerName` function returns the name of the current sampler, it cannot be used for running samplers based on condition. See update to my answer for solution.

Comment: Mea culpa, now it should be here

Comment: if answer is ok you should accept it and upvote so that other users know they can use it